# Install pendant light without ground wire or grounding screw

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling, lamp

I bought some secondhand [Belux Cloud 30](https://www.belux.com/en/catalog/all/cloud) pendant lights that didn’t come with the original ceiling box, and I’m trying to install it in the ceiling box from the pendant light that was previously installed.

The pendant light doesn’t appear to have a grounding wire or a screw on the plate.

What’s the best way to ground this?

[image: top of pendant light with white and black wires and two strings]

[image: box for previous lamp with white, black, and copper ground wires]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lights don't appear to be UL listed so I'd be thinking about not using them.

That being said, you'll need to get a grounding screw from your home store, probably a 10-32 screw, and screw it into that bracket in one of the small holes. Loop the ground wire from the ceiling around the screw and tighten. Trace the small white wires to see if they are ground wires, if the lights were UL approved, they'd be green. If they are ground wires to the bulb holders, fasten them to the end of the ground wire from the ceiling with a wire nut. If they are not wires, they may be meant to secure the cord from being pulled out too far.

Again, buying second hand lights with no instructions is a bad idea.